# Is it possible to inherit reflective access to anonymous child module?

Tags: java, reflection, java-platform-module-system, java-17

Let's say I write a module/library named `mylib` that uses an internal/hidden third party module/library named `internal`. The API of *mylib* does not expose any functionality from that third party library and it may be replaced by something else in the near future.

```java
module mylib {
    requires internal;
    exports some.pgk.from.mylib;
}
```

But here is my problem. The internal library needs reflective access to the classes/objects that are passed through the public API of *mylib* to do it's work.

An example application/module named `app` that utilizes my library would have to define the following moduleinfo.java

```java
module app {
    requires mylib;
    opens some.pkg.from.app to internal;
}
```

But this is bad, because it exposes the internally used module to the users of my library, and I would not be able to remove/change it in the future without breaking *app*. Ideally i would like to allow the module *internal* reflective access to all modules that are open to *mylib* instead:

```java
module app {
    requires mylib;
    opens some.pkg.from.app to mylib; // also open to internal without naming it
}
```

Can this be done with the current (Java 17) module system? Is there a good workaround in case this is not possible?

Comment: Well, you could call [`appModule.addOpens("some.pkg.from.app", internalModule)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#addOpens%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Module%29) from a class in the `mylib` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see four possible solutions:

1. Call [`appModule.addOpens("some.pkg.from.app", internalModule)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#addOpens%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Module%29) from `mylib`.

   > If this module has opened a package to at least the caller module then update this module to open the package to the given module.

   This works because `myapp` has opened the package `some.pkg.from.app` to the `mylib` module - which is the caller module.
   You have to repeat it for every package that has been opened to your module.
   If you don't deal with module layers, you can reflectively enumerate all packages that are open to your module.
   If you have to deal with layers - you have to enumerate all the layers - and those can be added at runtime.
2. Pass a `Consumer<AccessibleObject> makeAccessible = ao -> ao.setAccessible(true);` to `internal`.

   This works because now the caller of `setAccessible` is now `mylib`.
   (Or `myapp`, if the consumer came from there.)
3. Pass a full privilege [lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#lookup()) from `mylib` to `internal`.

   You can use this [Lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html) to call `AccessibleObject.setAccessible`.
   Or maybe do something else, like calling `Module.addOpens`.
4. Pass a full privilege lookup from `myapp` to `mylib`, which in turn passes it to `internal`.

   The benefit here is that you do not need to declare that you open a package - as any `MethodHandle` you lookup through the passed lookup will work as if it was called from `myapp`.
   You may even be able to restrict this lookup.

Comment: When you pass a fully privileged lookup object, you can not only use it to call `setAccessible` or `addOpens`, but also to acquire method handles which you may invoke or pass to the `LambdaMetafactory` to generate an implementation of an interface you can use to invoke the method later-on. Further, the caller may inject new classes into that context, into a target’s nest host for accessing private members when necessary, to help the particular use case.

Comment: If you design a new API, I'd always use a Lookup. If you do that, the full-privilege Lookup has (almost) the same capabilities as the bytecode of it's lookup class.